# Rederict works only in specefic browsers

Tags: php, internet-explorer, google-chrome

The following code rederict correctly in Chrome, but not in IE... why?

```
(...)
$x = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['x']);
$x = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['x']);
$x = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['x']);
$x = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['x']);
$MomentEvent = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['MomentEvent']);

     {
    $registerquery = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users_event (x, x, x, x, x, MomentEvent) VALUES('".$x."', '".$_SESSION ['x']."', '".$x."', '".$x."', '".$x."', '".$confirm_code=md5(uniqid (rand())). "'); ");
    if($registerquery)
    {
        echo "<h1>XXXX</h1>";
        echo "<p>XXXXX</p>";          
        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;show2.php?MomentEvent=<?php echo $MomentEvent ?>' />";
}
    else
    {
        echo "<h1>Error</h1>";
        echo "<p>Sorry, your registration failed. Please go back and try again.</p>";    
    }

(...)
```

Comment: No research effort. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/604dac15-564d-4111-844c-cfe5c36f0525/meta-httpequivrefresh-issue-with-ie-7 btw. I suggest header redirect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'd be better off using the `header()` function to send the appropriate HTTP header for a redirect, like this:

```
header( "show2.php?MomentEvent=" . $MomentEvent );
```

If you want to stick with the method you're currently using, you'll want to include the `URL=` attribute, so it would look like this:

```
<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;URL=show2.php?MomentEvent=<?php echo $MomentEvent; ?>' />
```

Comment: By the way, the rederict dosen't take the $MomentEvent value for the url... why? It simply show the url like it's wrote...

Comment: I'm not really following what you mean when you say that it's not taking the value. Can you clarify?

Comment: The $MomentEvent refer to a specific value in my MySQL table, that is entered with the info of the user. I want that value to be in the URL, to show the info of one user on a unique page.

Comment: The code is correct to show the $MomentEvent value. If it's not showing up in the output, then it doesn't contain anything.

Comment: Should I put something like $_GET(MomentEvent) before?

Comment: You would just need to put in there whatever variable holds your value. Whether that's `$_GET['MomentEvent']`, `$MomentEvent`, or something else is an issue separate from your original question.

Comment: This is the correct answer; you should accept it. For more on why not to use META redirection, see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/meta-refresh-causes-additional-http-requests.aspx